# Create Hierarchical Query to define SSIS package from log entries

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a framework to be used to start and monitor a SSIS package from an MVC application. I have most of it working, I am just at the point of trying to improve my monitor functionality so that I can display in the browser a representation of the package. I have been able to create a query that is able to uniquely identify all of the "source" components of the package, but this is just a flat representation and does not allow me to identify sequences and their associated steps for example.

What I would like to be able to do is create a hierarchical query of the SSIS log table, that will provide a representation like the following:

```
Package Start
   Step 1
   Sequence A
      Step A1
      Step A2
   Sequence B
      Step B1
      Step B2
   Step 2
   Sequence C
      Step C1
      Step C2
      Step C3
   Step 4
   Step 5
Package End
```

By being able to create the hierarchy I hope to be able to create a representation of the package in the browser, and unlike currently, only being able to display it in a flat table like structure, I should be able to place the sequence steps inside a sequence and give the user better feedback as to where the process is at.

An example of the log entries I would use to define the package (I would use entries from a previously run instance to get the definition) looks like this:

```
    id  event   computer    operator    source  sourceid    executionid starttime   endtime datacode    databytes   message
2478    PackageStart    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Package 3BC68A08-3B6E-4138-BC79-4B124A37FF60    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:56:58.000 2013-06-18 17:56:58.000 0   0x  Beginning of package execution.  
2479    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Package 3BC68A08-3B6E-4138-BC79-4B124A37FF60    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:56:58.000 2013-06-18 17:56:58.000 0   0x  
2480    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Receive Orders  96FEEE13-2053-4B6F-9EF6-13F063CBED0B    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:56:59.000 2013-06-18 17:56:59.000 0   0x  
2481    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Receive Orders  96FEEE13-2053-4B6F-9EF6-13F063CBED0B    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 100 0x  Executing query "DECLARE @RowCount INT  SET @RowCount = 0 WHILE @Ro...".
2482    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Receive Orders  96FEEE13-2053-4B6F-9EF6-13F063CBED0B    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 0   0x  
2483    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Status to Processing 4EE144BF-CA76-4BA5-B0B2-77E0899A22C0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 0   0x  
2484    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Status to Processing 4EE144BF-CA76-4BA5-B0B2-77E0899A22C0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 100 0x  Executing query "UPDATE [dbo].[Order] SET     [Status] = 2 WHERE   ...".
2485    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Status to Processing 4EE144BF-CA76-4BA5-B0B2-77E0899A22C0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 0   0x  
2486    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Clear dates before processing orders    BE85B6A1-07D0-41E6-B76D-9554348867A9    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 2013-06-18 17:57:06.000 0   0x  
2487    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Clear dates before processing orders    BE85B6A1-07D0-41E6-B76D-9554348867A9    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 100 0x  Executing query "UPDATE [dbo].[Order] SET      [ProcessedDate] = NU...".
2488    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Clear dates before processing orders    BE85B6A1-07D0-41E6-B76D-9554348867A9    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 0   0x  
2489    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Process Sequencer   4535503D-3DED-4D12-BE07-431A285A29F3    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 0   0x  
2490    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Set Processed Date  C027DF69-3006-4BB7-8F04-CD04DACF6910    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 2013-06-18 17:57:10.000 0   0x  
2491    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Set Processed Date  C027DF69-3006-4BB7-8F04-CD04DACF6910    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 100 0x  Executing query "UPDATE [dbo].[Order] SET     [ProcessedDate] = GET...".
2492    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Set Processed Date  C027DF69-3006-4BB7-8F04-CD04DACF6910    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 0   0x  
2493    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Create Pick List    680E0119-20A1-43A7-87F9-F4A0ECB292D0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 2013-06-18 17:57:15.000 0   0x  
2494    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Create Pick List    680E0119-20A1-43A7-87F9-F4A0ECB292D0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 100 0x  Executing query "INSERT [dbo].[PickList]     ([OrderID]     ,[Picke...".
2495    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Create Pick List    680E0119-20A1-43A7-87F9-F4A0ECB292D0    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 0   0x  
2496    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Process Sequencer   4535503D-3DED-4D12-BE07-431A285A29F3    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 0   0x  
2497    OnPreExecute    {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Shipping Date    2C9E46A4-FDCE-425B-AC46-666B783CFD44    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 2013-06-18 17:57:28.000 0   0x  
2498    OnProgress      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Shipping Date    2C9E46A4-FDCE-425B-AC46-666B783CFD44    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 100 0x  Executing query "UPDATE [dbo].[Order] SET     [ShippedDate] = GETUT...".
2499    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Update Shipping Date    2C9E46A4-FDCE-425B-AC46-666B783CFD44    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 0   0x  
2500    OnPostExecute   {MACHINE}               {USER}          Package 3BC68A08-3B6E-4138-BC79-4B124A37FF60    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 0   0x  
2501    PackageEnd      {MACHINE}               {USER}          Package 3BC68A08-3B6E-4138-BC79-4B124A37FF60    086AEB95-717E-4EED-850F-A403BF4D4B0D    2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 2013-06-18 17:57:32.000 0   0x  End of package execution.
```

I've created queries before that have a parent child relationship of fields in the table, but for this I need to identify all of the records that appear between the PackageStart and PackageEnd or OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute events of the same sourceid.

This would additionally need to be filtered to only use a specific executionid so that you analyse one instance of the package (easily done use a max on the id column for a given sourceid and PackageEnd event you can identify a single executionid).

Any ideas on how to piece this together in a SQL Statement because this is a little out of my knowledge area now?

Comment: The above logic presumes you never run tasks in parallel, doesn't it?

Comment: @billinkc yes I am making that presumption and have created the framework to ensure that these packages are not started in parallel. I am investigating other ways to get this information, but since I already am getting the flat representation of the package using a SQL statement, I thought it should be possible to create a hierarchical query to get the structured information.

Comment: @billinkc thinking about it, it wouldn't matter because if you are filtering on the executionid, even if they are running simultaneously you would get the information required anyway.

Comment: I was not referring to the same package running in parallel but tasks within the package itself executing in parallel. http://i.stack.imgur.com/arFvd.png At any rate, I'll see if I can play with some data later on and get you an answer.

Comment: @billinkc sorry I see what you meant now. Yes as far as I know, all the packages that will be run through this are sequentially executed tasks. This type of solution would not be suitable for packages that have asynchronous tasks.